# How to add multiple element using appendChild to a parent element?

Tags: javascript

I am practising DOM manipulation using native JS my issue right now is I used a table and I am having a problem in appending my multiple columns to the table row "". Here's what I did but it will only add the first column I created.

```
let form = document.querySelector('#form-task');
let taskTable = document.querySelector('#tasklist-table tbody');

let addTask = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let task_description = document.querySelector('#input-task-description').value;
    let task_notes = document.querySelector('#input-task-notes').value;

    let row = document.createElement('tr');

    // task description
    let col1 = document.createElement('td');
    col1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task_description));

    // task note
    let col2 = document.createElement('td');
    col2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task_notes));

    // delete button
    let col3 = document.createElement('td');

    // create button delete
    let btn_del = document.createElement('button');
    btn_del.className = 'button alert tiny center-btn"';
    btn_del.appendChild(document.createTextNode('x'));

    // append button to columnd 3
    col3.appendChild(btn_del);

    row.appendChild(col1, col2, col3); // IT IS NOT WORKING, HOW CAN I MERGE MY CREATED COLUMN THEN PASS TO THE ROW?

    // append row to table
    taskTable.appendChild(row);

}
```

Comment: Please read this for better understanding https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186970/append-multiple-children-to-a-node-at-once

Comment: In `btn_del.className = 'button alert tiny center-btn"';`, is that double quote supposed to be there?

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild` only accepts a *single child* as an argument to be appended.

While you could call `row.appendChild` multiple times with the 3 `<td>`s, it might be easier to create the td *and* append it to the tr at the same time, and to use `textContent` instead of `createTextNode`:

```
const taskDescription = document.querySelector('#input-task-description').value;
const taskNotes = document.querySelector('#input-task-notes').value;

const row = taskTable.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
row.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).textContent = taskDescription;
row.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).textContent = taskNotes;
const delTd = row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
const delBtn = delTd.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
delBtn.className = 'button alert tiny center-btn"';
delBtn.textContent = 'x';
```

Comment: Wow nice answer, I forgot that I can use chaining method also. And it looks like it is much better so that I don't need to create a multiple variables assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Please do append child separately.

```
row.appendChild(col1);
row.appendChild(col2);
row.appendChild(col3);
```

Comment: Nice, I never thought that you can actually create multiple appendChild assignment like that. :)

Comment: @rochellecanale Sure, why not? Most functions/methods can be called any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

To get something close to your original attempt, you can just put the elements to be appended in an array, and iterate that array.

```
[col1, col2, col3].forEach(col => row.appendChild(col));
```

That's not too far off from where you wanted to be.

---

However, I'm inclined toward making a function that receives an object structure representing the DOM structure you're creating.

```js
let addTask = (e) => {
//    e.preventDefault();
    
    const taskTable = document.querySelector("#task-table");

    const task_description = document.querySelector('#input-task-description').value;
    const task_notes = document.querySelector('#input-task-notes').value;

    create({
      name: "tr",
      children: [
        {name: "td", textContent: task_description},
        {name: "td", textContent: task_notes},
        {name: "td", children: [
          {name: "button", className: "button alert tiny center-btn", textContent: "x"},
        ]},
      ],
    }, taskTable);

}

addTask();
addTask();
addTask();

console.log(document.querySelector("#task-table").outerHTML);

function create(obj, parent=document.createDocumentFragment()) {
  if (!obj) return parent;

  if (typeof obj === "string") {
    parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj));
    return parent;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(o => create(o, parent));
    return parent;
  }

  const {name, children, ...props} = obj;
  if (!name || typeof name !== "string") {
    return parent; // or throw exception
  }

  const el = parent.appendChild(document.createElement(name));
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(props || {})) {
    el[key] = val;
  }

  return create(children, el);
}
```

```html
<input id=input-task-description value=foo>
<input id=input-task-notes value=bar>

<table id=task-table>

</table>
```

This is just an example implementation, but you can create your DOM structures in a very concise and clear way like this.

Comment: This is starting to sound like JSX (I only name that one because I am most familiar with it), only more complex. Is there some reason you’re trying to write your own web framework when the OP didn’t even ask for one?

Comment: @BrianDrake: It's nothing close to a framework. It's a very small, focused utility. What do you find complex about creating a DOM node from an object with properties that describe the node?